# Splitting a JavaScript string when any one if given delimitters occur

Tags: javascript, tokenize

I used `String.split(a)` method. It breaks the string into some parts when `a` ooccurs as substring. But what I want is I will give a list of delimitters and string will be broken into pieces when any one of those delimitters occur. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex in the split

```
'abcdef'.split(/[bdf]/) //[ 'a', 'c', 'e', '' ]
```

Or even

```
'abcdef'.split(/b|d|f/) //[ 'a', 'c', 'e', '' ]
```

Also splitting on string

```
'Hello There World'.split(/\s?There\s?|\s+/) //[ 'Hello', 'World' ]
```

`\s?` to grab any spaces that may be with the word

Comment: What if I want to add a string and a character both as delimitter?

Comment: @taufique Add a string? Like a word? Then group the string in the regex. Basically anything that makes the regex match will be used to split. You should research regex

Comment: Would you please edit your answer for that case too?

Comment: @taufique—`/bc|f/` splits on 'bc' and 'f'.

Comment: @taufique Splitting with both a "string" and a character:  `/puppy|kitten|[bdf]/`